# Почему переменная count считает неправильно?

Tags: java

```
public class Artefact {
   int count;
   String culture;
   int year;

   public Artefact() {
      this.count = count++;
      this.culture = "Unknown culture " + this.count;
   }

   public Artefact(int count, String culture) {
      this.count = count++;
      this.culture = culture;
   }

   public Artefact(int cont, String culture, int year) {
      this.count = count++;
      this.culture = culture;
      this.year = year;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Artefact one = new Artefact();
      Artefact two = new Artefact(2, "Atlantic");
      Artefact three = new Artefact(3, "Russia", 19);
      System.out.println(one.culture);
      System.out.println(two.culture + " № " + two.count);
      System.out.println(three.culture + " " +three.year + " century" + " № " +three.count);



   }

}
```

Вывод на консоль:

> Unknown culture 0
>   Atlantic № 2
>   Russia 19 century № 0

Само задание:

> Твоя задача — спроектировать класс Artifact.
>   Артефакты, которые хранятся в музее, бывают трех видов.
>   Первый — о которых неизвестно ничего, кроме порядкового номера, присвоенному музеем (например: 212121).
>   Второй — о которых известен порядковый номер и культура, которой он был создан (например: 212121, "Ацтеки").
>   Третий вид — о которых известен порядковый номер, культура, которой он был создан, и точный век его создания (например: 212121, "Ацтеки", 12).
>
> Создай класс Artifact, описывающий хранящиеся в музее древности, и напиши необходимое количество конструкторов для него. В методе main() создай по одному артефакту каждого вида.

Comment: Потому что код дублируется с ошибками.

Comment: А какие у меня конкретно ошибки не могли бы сказать?

Comment: Если метод майн, как я поняла, выполняет все поля по очереди, то переменная должна каждый раз увеличиваться на 1... или я что то не так понимаю?

Comment: Я уже пробовала делать ее статической, так же самая ерунда выскакивает

Comment: в зачем инкремент в конструкторе? вы хотите экземпляры посчитать?

Comment: в третьем конструкторе опечатка

Comment: Ну да, задание такое, что каждому экземпляру классу нужно присваивать номер по порядку

Comment: что то не могу понять какая у меня опечатся в третьем конструкторе....

Comment: Ребята, можно объяснение для тупых... что конкретно не так?!

Comment: в третьем конструкторе переменная называется cont а затем count

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы посчитать экземпляры можно воспользоваться статическим полем, при этом не придется явно оперировать индексами из создающего кода:

```
public class Artefact {

   static int counter;
   int count;
   String culture;
   int year;

   public Artefact() {
      this.count = counter++;
      this.culture = "Unknown culture " + this.count;
   }

   public Artefact(String culture) {
     this.count = counter++;
     this.culture = culture;
   }

   public Artefact(String culture, int year) {
     this(culture);
     this.year = year;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Artefact one = new Artefact();
       Artefact two = new Artefact("Atlantic");
       Artefact three = new Artefact("Russia", 19);
       System.out.println(one.culture);
       System.out.println(two.culture + " № " + two.count);
       System.out.println(three.culture + " " +three.year + " century" + " № " +three.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не соответствует условиям задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Значение счётчика надо брать из последнего созданного экземпляра.

```
Artefact one = new Artefact();
Artefact two = new Artefact(one.count, "Atlantic");
Artefact three = new Artefact(two.count, "Russia", 19);
```

Comment: тогда проблема, если создавать из разных мест

Comment: Нет никакой проблемы.

Comment: кроме того, чтобы заботиться о том, как получить ссылку на последний созданный экземпляр

Comment: Ну да,  чтобы не заботиться можно было бы создать репозиторий в котором хранить все объекты.